# Get timestamp difference using Ant

Tags: ant, timestamp

I need to calculate time difference using Ant.
Basically it has 2 variables. One is assigned the current time, and the other one has a different time. I need to get the time difference using Ant. Something like below. If anyone have code please reply.

```
variable a = current time;
variable b = different time
echo (a - b) ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing Simple Calculations with Native Ant Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619823/performing-simple-calculations-with-native-ant-tasks)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a much simpler solution:

```
<script language="javascript">
  project.setProperty('startTime', new Date().getTime());
</script>
...
<script language="javascript">
  project.setProperty('elapsedTime', new Date().getTime() - startTime)
</script>
<echo>Elapsed time: ${elapsedTime} ms</echo>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Java 16 and ant 1.9.13. The error message is `Unable to create javax script engine for javascript`. Do I need some optional component in order to be able to use javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @LeFunes answer (and uses the `tstamp` task)

```
<tstamp prefix="task.start">
<format property="millis" pattern="SSS"/>
</tstamp>
<tstamp prefix="task">
  <format property="start" pattern="E, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss"/>
</tstamp>
<time-consuming-task/>
<tstamp prefix="task.stop">
<format property="millis" pattern="SSS"/>
</tstamp>
<tstamp prefix="task">
  <format property="stop" pattern="E, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss"/>
</tstamp>
<script language="javascript">
  project.setProperty("task.diff", 
    Math.abs(
      (Date.parse(project.getProperty("task.stop")) +
         +project.getProperty("task.stop.millis")) - 
      (Date.parse(project.getProperty("task.start")) + 
         +project.getProperty("task.start.millis"))))
</script>
<echo>
  task completed in ${task.diff} ms
</echo>
```

NOTE:
 <strike>this doesn't consider milliseconds</strike>
 updated to consider the milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TEST ANT" default="test" basedir="..">
    <target name="test" description="">

        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
            var ts1 = new Date();
            project.setProperty("current.time.1", ts1.toLocaleString());
            project.setProperty("current.time.1.mill", ts1.getTime());
        ]]></script>
        <echo>Timestamp 1: ${current.time.1} [${current.time.1.mill}]</echo>

        <sleep milliseconds="1300"></sleep>

        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
            var ts2 = new Date();
            project.setProperty("current.time.2", ts2.toLocaleString());
            project.setProperty("current.time.2.mill", ts2.getTime());
        ]]></script>
        <echo>Timestamp 2: ${current.time.2} [${current.time.2.mill}]</echo>

        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
            project.setProperty("res", project.getProperty("current.time.2.mill")-project.getProperty("current.time.1.mill"));
        ]]></script>
        <echo>Diff: ${res}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JavaScript, you can use the [Math task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/math_task.html) provided by the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) utilities.

The Ant-Contrib are fairly old, and I don't know if anyone is still maintaining them, but they're very popular to use in Ant build files since they add some very useful tasks.

I recommend including the `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` into the project itself. When other people use your project, they'll also have the Ant-Contrib jar. I put `ant-lib/ac/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` under your project's home directory. I use `ant-lib` for all of my optional jars:

```
<project name="my.project"
    ...
    xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

   ...

    <taskdef uri="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib"
        resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/ac"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    ....
```

Now, you can use your math task like this:

```
    <ac:math result="time.diff"
        operation="-"
        operand1="${diff.time}"
        operand2="${initial.time}"/>
```

The `ac:` is an XML namespace that was declared in your `<project/>` entity, and was connected to your tasks via the `uri` parameter in the `<taskdef/>` entity. This allows you to have multiple optional Ant tasks that may have tasks with duplicate names. This is a good idea in case you use multiple optional task libraries that have the same task names.