# Ant script - Using Javascript Date.parse

Tags: javascript, debugging, ant, rhino, date-parsing

I am trying to experiment with the Script defined in [Get timestamp difference using ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243787/get-timestamp-difference-using-ant) SO question.

When I use the Date.parse as given in the example, I get a NullPointerException on the line for Javascript i.e. on this line

```
<script language="javascript" >
```

It seems to be somehow related to the Date.parse call, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

```
  <script language="javascript" >
  <![CDATA[
     println("calc js");
     project.setProperty("task.diff",
     Math.abs(
     (Date.parse(project.getProperty("task.stop")) +
     +project.getProperty("task.stop.millis")) -
     (Date.parse(project.getProperty("task.start")) +
     +project.getProperty("task.start.millis"))))
     ]]>
```

When I used the same concept in another script, making some changes to the original script, I get a different error -

javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: missing ) after argument list (#7) in  at line number 7

Here I am sending startTime and endTime as attributes to a macrodef and defining the script inside it.

```
            project.setProperty("task.diff", 
                           Math.abs(
                             Date.parse(@{startTime}) - 
                             Date.parse(@{endtime})
                                    )
                               );
```

How can I go about debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`sun.org.mozilla` refers to the Rhino JavaScript engine. `Date.parse()` is not supported by Rhino, unless you have a recent version:

[New in Rhino 1.7R3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/New_in_Rhino_1.7R3)

Use the Rhino console to check the version:

```
java -jar $RHINOPATH/js.jar #Rhino, `$RHINOPATH` is environment specific 
jrunscript -q #Rhino via Mustang
```

**References**

- [Command Line Shell Scripting in Mustang](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/command_line_script_shell_in)
- [Java 6 Scripting is no js.jar](https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/java-6-scripting-is-no-js-jar/)
- [e4X is not Mustang](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/e4x_is_not_mustang)
- [JavaScript Debugging Tips for Mustang](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/javascript_debugging_tips_for_mustang)
- [More JavaScript Debugging Tips for Mustang](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/more_javascript_debugging_tips_mustang)